# Convert values to keys in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

As far as MongoDB provides `$group` approach in aggregate pipeline, it returns list of documents, where `_id` keeps some "distinct" grouping value and other field keeps array of documents,  grouped by given condition.

What I want is to return a single document where the properties are the results of the aggregation.

Example collection:

```
{author: "Author1", title: "Title1"}
{author: "Author2", title: "Title2"}
{author: "Author2", title: "Title3"}
```

The aggregation

```
db.getCollection('books').aggregate([ 
    {"$group": {
           _id: "$author",
           books: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
          }
    }
])
```

This gives me the following output:

```
{_id: 'Author1', books: [{author: "Author1", title: "Title1"}]},
{_id: 'Author2', books: [{author: "Author2", title: "Title2"}, {author: "Author2", title: "Title3"}]}
```

But i would like to get the results as one single object like this:

```
{
  Author1: [
    {author: "Author1", title: "Title1"}
  ],
  Author2: [ 
    {author: "Author2", title: "Title2"},
    {author: "Author2", title: "Title3"}
  ]
}
```

In simple words, i want to use `_id` property as new field in resulting document, and proper `$group` values for specific `_id` must be value of new variable.

If somebody faced with such a queries, please, assist with that or give some clues how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

```
db.getCollection('books').aggregate([ 
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$author",
    "books": { "$push": "$$ROOT" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": {
      "$push": { "k": "$_id", "v": "$books" }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }}
])
```